# Is it possible to subscribe to Azure IOT Edge Device

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Hopefully a simple question, but with all the reading I have done about IOT Edge Devices, I still cannot find an answer.

For my application, I would like to have a local offline view of all the data going into the edge device and an online view from a website. Is it possible to subscribe to all the events in the Edge Device, just like how I am able to subscribe to all the events in the IOT Hub?

Hopefully something like this

Device->IOTEdge->IOTHub->Website
_______________->Local View (offline)

Comment: What do you mean by offline? If you send the data to IoT Hub first, you need to be online to read the data from there?!

Comment: I probably should have just gone into this before, but my use case is a homemade go cart. I want to be able to have a digital dash and be able to see the information from the pit during races. Digital dash needs to be run at the edge to latency issues and connectivity issues at different tracks. It is also vital that the dash is always running.

Comment: so you actually want something like this?! Device->IOTEdge->Website (offline, on the device itself) (without the data going out to IoT Hub in the cloud)

Comment: I want it to go to both places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen I can use the components to create a website and do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a local Azure IoT Edge webpage dashboard then look at Sander van de Velde blog for details and ideas. Sander has also a lot of other very good examples.

https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2018/12/07/create-your-own-local-azure-iot-edge-dashboard/
https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2018/04/20/visualizing-azure-iot-edge-using-local-dashboard/

You just need one nodejs module listening messages from edgeHub and sending messages using websocket connection. Then you can use same or another module to serve static webpage aka your dashboard. You can access this local dashboard from the same local network without any connection to internet. And you can also send your messages to upstream (IoTHub in cloud) and do the same there. I have used nodejs websocket locally in the edge and SignalR to stream data to cloud dashboards.